# SpringBoot and Sanitizing @PathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sanitization, fortify

In our project we are currently using Fortify scanner to scan our code, and we have an interesting question. We are considering that something like

```
@PathVariable (required = true) String id
```

Is sanitized already by Spring, but in our case it is raising an issue when used in the following context

```
@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
        path = "/{id}",
        consumes = "application/json"
)
public ResponseEntity cancelTask(
        @PathVariable (required = true) String id,
        @RequestBody (required = false) String reason
) {
    String userId = authenticationContext.getUserId();
    if (!authorizationService.hasPermission(userId, id, TaskAccessRight.EDIT)) {            log.warn("User {} is not authorized to cancel task {}", userId, id);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Not authorized to cancel task " + id);
    }
 ...
}
```

Fortify flags this as a Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected issue.

My question is it really possible to exploit by saying that id is something like

```
<script>alert('Hello Jack')</script>
```

as path input... if so how should we sanitize it in the body?

We are not certain that this is sanitized, soo we are not sure it is a false positive, can someone confirm Spring takes care of this automaticly?

We have dozens of similar issues raised by fortify

Comment: Did you try actually sending a string with HTML+Javascript through the `@PathVariable`? I get either a 500 - `The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String \"//\"` or 400 - `The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)`. It seems to me Spring blocks forward slashes (e.g. (escaped/encoded) that are not part of the path heirarchy.

Comment: Just to clarify, is Fortify flagging the "id" path variable, the "reason" parameter, or both? Does it explicitly tell you the "id" parameter is a vulnerability? I would assume the "reason" parameter would get flagged.

Answer (score 1):

Based on static code analysis, this fortify finding makes sense.
String id is an input to your method, your code is not validating or sanitizing the input and in case of UNAUTHORIZED your code is returning it. So the "bad" code is flowing through your application and fortify and I do not know what the client is doing with the response, so there is some kind of risk.

Spring does not take care of this automatically!

You could use Hibernate-Validator (see Maven Library spring-boot-starter-validation) to validate the input and reject invalid input like your script.
In my German blog, I have written an article about Spring and validation, see:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/11/validation-with-spring.html

Comment: Ahh, so it does not do this. Indeed in that case it is a real issue. Thanks I will look for simple ways to do output sanitization that are not very intrusive.

Comment: From my point of view it is very simple. You add one Maven Dependency, add `@Validated` annotation on Controller class and `@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Z]{1,10}")` (use the regex you want) annotation in front of your id attribute. That is all.

Comment: ill try to google translate your article. Thks